# inject custom service into httpProvider interceptors

Tags: angularjs

if I have created service in angularjs

```
 .module("common.services")
    .factory("redirectService",
            ["$resource", "$q", "$location", 
             redirectService]);

function redirectService($resource, $q, $location){
   ...
}
```

how can I inject this service into httpProvider interceptors?
I've found some *working example* which I need to inject somewhere? should I paste this code inside this redirect service or inside app.js config?

```
module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push("redirectService");
}
```

Comment: you cannot inject custom services into `.config`, only internal angular functions. use the `.run` block for that stuff.

Comment: can you please provide example as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put it on your app.js

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', ['common.services']);

module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push("redirectService");
}
```